# The $\omega$-limit set of a trajectory of an autonomous ODE is an invariant set for the ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following ODE

$$x'(t) = h(x(t)), x(0) = \bar{x} $$ where $h$ is lipschitz

For some solution trajectory $x(t)$ its omega limit set is defined as $=\bigcap_t \overline{\{x(s): s> t\}}$. I want to prove that it is an invariant set for the ODE.

i.e. for any other solution of the ODE $y(.)$ if there exist an increasing sequence $\{t_n\}$ tending to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity and $x(t_n) \to  y(0)$ then I need to find an increasing sequence $\{t'_n\}$ (depending on $t$) tending to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity such that  $ x(t'_n) \to y(t) $ . $x(.)$ and $y(.)$ are unrelated other than they are solutions to the same ODE. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that, given the system $\dot x=h(x)$ its omega limit set is invariant. Literally it means that if $y\in \omega$-limit set than the solution $x(t;y)$ is also in omega limit set. We have that there exists a sequence $(t_k)$ such that $x(t_k;x_0)\to y$. Now for a fixed $t$ consider $x(t+t_k;x_0)$. By the properties of the solution $x(t+t_k;x_0)=x(t;x(t_k;x_0))\to x(t;y)$, which actually implies that $x(t;y)$ is in omega limit set.

Comment: So, you are assuming that $h$ is lipschitz as you use continuity of the solution as a function of initial point. Yeah, It seems like it is true under lipschitz continuity assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I doubt that this is the cleanest solution, but it seems to work.

Here I assume, by the way, that $h$ is Lipschitz, which by Picard-Lindelof is enough to guarantee existence and uniqueness for any given initial condition; in fact I don't think this hypothesis can be lifted wholly.

Let $\bar{y}$ be an element of the omega limit set $S_x := \bigcap_t \overline{\{x(s) : s > t\}}$, say, it is the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} y(t_n)$, and let $y(t)$ be the solution such that $y_0 = \bar{y}$.

First, if $h(\bar{y}) = 0$, then $y(t) = \bar{y}$ is a (constant) solution, and trivially the solution stays in $S_t$ for all $t > 0$.

So, henceforth suppose not. If $h(\bar{y}) > 0$ is positive, so that $h$ is positive on some interval $I := (\bar{y} - \epsilon, \bar{y} + \epsilon)$. Then, for sufficiently large $n$, $x(t_n) \in I$; for each $n$, if $x(t_n) \leq \bar{y}$, then there is some small $\Delta_n \geq 0$ such that $x(t_n + \Delta_n) = \bar{y}$. If the reverse inequality holds, the same argument applies flowing backward in time. A similar argument holds if $h(\bar{y}) < 0$. Either way, we get a sequence of times $\tau_n := t_n + \Delta_n$ that tends to infinity and such that $x(\tau_n) = \bar{y}$.

Now, any value $y$ achieves after $0$ can be written as $y(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$. Since the differential equation is homogeneous, $x(t + \tau_n)$ is also a solution to the IVP with $y(0) = \bar{y}$ for all $n$; in particular $x(\alpha + \tau_n) = y(\alpha)$ for all $n$, but the times $\alpha + t_n$ also tend to infinity, and so $y(\alpha) \in S_x$. Since $\alpha$ is arbitrary, $y(t) \in S_x$ for all $t \geq 0$.

Comment: what is the violation ? I claim that limit sets for a trajectory is an invariant set of the ODE i.e. if any other trajectory starts there it will be totally contained there.

Comment: As I understand it you've defined an omega set in terms of a particular solution, and you want to know whether that set is an invariant of the ODE, i.e., whether the set is independent of the choice of particular solution (presumably defined, say, on some interval $(t_0, \infty)$).

Comment: invariant set and omega limit set are two different things. As far as I know, omega limit set is specific to a trajectory and invariant set is specific to an ODE.

Comment: I see, in that case the last sentence of your first paragraph is perhaps confusing ("prove that it is an invariant set"). Anything I think I understand now, and I think the claim is true; in fact I think it is a general feature of homogeneous ODEs, which should be related to the fact that if $x(t)$ is a solution, then so is $x(t + t_0)$ for all $t_0$.

Comment: I don't understand how that proves that omega limit set for a "trajectory" is an invariant set for the "ODE".

Comment: My point in my original answer is that it's not; the explanation in the previous comment addresses the "i.e." of your question, which, if I understand it correctly, asks something different than your first paragraph does.

Comment: Oh sorry. Now, the first and second paragraph are same.

Comment: What is your definition of invariant set?

Comment: An invariant set of an "ODE" is a set $A$ such that "any" trajectory of the ODE initiated at $A$ remains in $A$ for all $t$ i.e for any trajectory $x(.)$, if $x(0) \in A$ then $x(t) \in A$ $\forall t$.

Comment: I've put together a proof, see above.

Comment: The below answer is easier. Also, it is true under lipschitz continuity only.

Comment: @user148951 Yes, that's very clean, nice work.